# Need Help to find an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have some data in Column A such as 1-2-3-0-5-2-1 and in column "B" A-F-E-G-C-B-D now I want to sort column A and B's Data based on Column A's Value then what will be the formula if I want to rearrange them in another two cells. I got a formula to sort Column A's Value `=SORT(FILTER(A1:A8,A1:A8 <>0))` but I want to sort both columns in a single formula Image one for Existing Data and image two what I Looking for

[image]

I want to sort both columns in a single formula

Comment: Where's the second image?

Comment: Try: `=SORT(FILTER(A1:B7,A1:A7<>0),{1,2})` but there is no image two

Comment: @Alauddiin just posted in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP mentioned as the given formula is working for them hence posting it as an answer.

[image]

---

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=SORT(FILTER(A1:B7,A1:A7<>0),{1,2})
```

---